# Get Status of Pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I am using `Set-AzureRmDataFactoryPipelineActivePeriod` to schedule the pipeline via PowerShell. However I am trying to get hold of Azure Commandlet that can give me the completion status of the pipeline once scheduled OR the code should run into some loop till the time the pipeline has not completed.

Answer (score 1):

#### ADF v2

For v2 of Azure DataFactory, you can use `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun` cmdlet to get pipeline runs from some time period.
Parameters you need to set are `ResourceGroupName`, `DataFactoryName`, `LastUpdatedAfter` and `-LastUpdatedBefore` and optionally `PipelineName`.

For example, if you wanted to get pipeline runs from the last hour, for your pipeline *my-pipeline* in *my-adf* DataFactory in resource group *my-rg*, you would execute something like

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName "my-rg" `
        -DataFactoryName "my-adf" `
        -PipelineName "my-pipeline" `
        -LastUpdatedAfter (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) `
        -LastUpdatedBefore (Get-Date).AddHours(1)
```

For more information, here's the cmdlet documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactoryv2pipelinerun?view=azurermps-4.4.1

#### ADF v1

If you are using ADF v1, you can invoke `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun` cmdlet to get pipeline status.However, since in DataFactory v1 output dataset slice is what runs the schedule for pipeline execution, you need to pass your output dataset name as well. Below is an example how you would invoke that cmdlet to get slices from the past hour

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun -ResourceGroupName "my-rg" `
        -DataFactoryName "my-adf" `
        -DatasetName "my-dataset" `
        -StartDateTime (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
```

For more information, here's the cmdlet documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactoryrun?view=azurermps-5.0.0

Comment: Thanks. I however get below error when I try to run :

`$run =Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName "my-rg" 
        -DataFactoryName "mtdf" 
        -PipelineName "mypl" 
        -LastUpdatedAfter (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) 
        -LastUpdatedBefore (Get-Date).AddHours(1)

Write-Host  $run.Status `


` Error:
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun : HTTP Status Code: Forbidden
Error Code: Forbidden
Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
Request Id: 0c2f14ce-fc13-4d2f-a402-861ca68622d6
Timestamp (Utc):11/29/2017 05:35:58 `

Comment: Before using any of these ADF cmdlets, you should login into your azure account using `Login-AzureRmAccount` cmdlet. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I used that still got the error:
I later figured out that probably,the V2 in command:Invoke-` AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline ` is for data factory V2 version where as we are still to migrate on that version

I tried below work around
` $run= (Get-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline  -ResourceGroupName 'my-rg' -DataFactoryName 'mydf' -Name 'salespipeline').properties.RuntimeInfo | select PipelineState -ExpandProperty PipelineState `

Above cmdd gives only the run state of the pipeline whether its in running state or complete but I am also interested in knowing if pipeline has passed or failed

Comment: I didn't realize you were using ADF v1. I've now updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Got below code, but from where do we get the $Runid?

```
while ($True) {
    $run = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -PipelineRunId $runId

    if ($run) {
        if ($run.Status -ne 'InProgress') {
            Write-Host "Pipeline run finished. The status is: " $run.Status -foregroundcolor "Yellow"
            $run
            break
        }
        Write-Host  "Pipeline is running...status: InProgress" -foregroundcolor "Yellow"
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The RunID comes from every pipeline run. With PowerShell, you can Invoke a pipeline and capture the RunID from that cmdlet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline?view=azurermps-4.4.1

There is an example of setting $RunID in this PS script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/scripts/incremental-copy-powershell?toc=%2fpowershell%2fmodule%2ftoc.json

Comment: Same issue with Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline:

`Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline : HTTP Status Code: Forbidden
Error Code: Forbidden
Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`